# Retrieving FromBodyAttribute On Argument from Minimal APi - InvocationContext.Arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis, asp.net-minimal-apis

I am trying to write a c# MinimalApi EndpointFilter validator for ComponentModel DataAnnotations. What I have is working fine when passing in a type to validate against but I am trying to make it a bit more generic to pull the type from the [FromBody] attribute of the InvocationContext. My best try is below but an example call returns null:

```
var fromBody = invocationContext.Arguments
    .Where(w => Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(w.GetType(), typeof(FromBodyAttribute)) is not null);
```

I am not sure this is possible but would be happy with any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FromBodyAttribute` usually is not applied to the argument type but to the handler function parameter (note that there are some edge cases for example when [`AsParametersAttribute` is used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#parameter-binding-for-argument-lists-with-asparameters)). To analyze the handler function parameters you need to use endpoint filter factory, not the filter:

```
app.MapPost("/foo", ([FromBody] SomeType t) => "bar")
    .AddEndpointFilterFactory((filterFactoryContext, next) =>
    {
        var parameters = filterFactoryContext.MethodInfo.GetParameters();
        var bodyParams = parameters
            .Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttributes<FromBodyAttribute>().Any())
            .ToArray();
        return invocationContext => next(invocationContext); // create filter based on handler parameters
    });
```

See the [Filters in Minimal API apps: Register a filter using an endpoint filter factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#register-a-filter-using-an-endpoint-filter-factory) doc for more info.

Comment: That may be what I need. I was using "builder.AddEndpointFilter(async (invocationContext, next) => ..." where builder is the RouteHandlerBuilder.  I will take a look at your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this info. I didn't post at the time but your response gave me a solution to a generic dataannotations  validation solution for .net c# Minimal Api. 

A few days ago I posted a Q / A summarizing the approach if you are interested. [Using DataAnnotation Model Validation in Asp.net Minimal Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78014553/using-dataannotation-model-validation-in-asp-net-minimal-api)